# Unknown type 'LONG' for column 'endt_text' in schema Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

How do I fix this error in my schema? It says Unknown type 'LONG' for column 'endt_text'. My database is oracle 10g.

```
 Could not dump table "gipi_endttext" because of following StandardError
  Unknown type 'LONG' for column 'endt_text'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this error by creating my own migration file and migrate to change the datatype of endt_text from long to text.

```
 class ChangeGipiEndttext < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
   def change
     change_column(:gipi_endttext, :endt_text, :text)
  end

  def up
        change_column :gipi_endttext, :endt_text, :text
  end
  def down
        change_column :gipi_endttext, :endt_text, :long
  end
end
```